# How can i calculate the unclaimed amount from Uniswap v3 position

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3

How can i calculate the unclaimed amount from Uniswap v3 position( with any addresses) like https://app.apy.vision/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have this script to get unclaimed owed fees. Its in .mjs format js/typescript so should be easily converted to either

```
import { JSBI } from "@uniswap/sdk";
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import * as fs from 'fs';


    // ERC20 json abi file
let ERC20Abi = fs.readFileSync('<path>/ERC20.json');
const ERC20 = JSON.parse(ERC20Abi);

    // V3 pool abi json file
let pool = fs.readFileSync('<path>/V3PairAbi.json');
const IUniswapV3PoolABI = JSON.parse(pool);

    // V3 factory abi json
let facto = fs.readFileSync('<path>/V3factory.json');
const IUniswapV3FactoryABI = JSON.parse(facto);

    // V3 NFT manager abi
let NFT = fs.readFileSync('<path>/UniV3NFT.json');
const IUniswapV3NFTmanagerABI = JSON.parse(NFT);


const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/<API_Key>")


    // V3 standard addresses (different for celo)
const factory = "0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984";
const NFTmanager = "0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88";



async function getData(tokenID){
    var FactoryContract = new ethers.Contract(factory, IUniswapV3FactoryABI, provider);

    var NFTContract =  new ethers.Contract(NFTmanager, IUniswapV3NFTmanagerABI, provider);
    var position = await NFTContract.positions(tokenID);
    
    var token0contract =  new ethers.Contract(position.token0, ERC20, provider);
    var token1contract =  new ethers.Contract(position.token1, ERC20, provider);
    var Decimal0 = await token0contract.decimals();
    var Decimal1 = await token1contract.decimals();
    
    var token0sym = await token0contract.symbol();
    var token1sym = await token1contract.symbol();
    
    var V3pool = await FactoryContract.getPool(position.token0, position.token1, position.fee);
    var poolContract = new ethers.Contract(V3pool, IUniswapV3PoolABI, provider);

    var slot0 = await poolContract.slot0();
    var tickLow = await poolContract.ticks(position.tickLower.toString());
    var tickHi = await poolContract.ticks(position.tickUpper.toString());
    
    var feeGrowthGlobal0 = await poolContract.feeGrowthGlobal0X128();
    var feeGrowthGlobal1 = await poolContract.feeGrowthGlobal1X128();
    
    var pairName = token0sym +"/"+ token1sym;
    
    var PoolInfo = {
    "Pair": pairName, 
    "Decimal0": Decimal0, 
    "Decimal1": Decimal1, 
    "tickCurrent": slot0.tick, 
    "tickLow": position.tickLower, 
    "tickHigh": position.tickUpper, 
    "liquidity": position.liquidity.toString(), 
    "feeGrowth0Low": tickLow.feeGrowthOutside0X128.toString(),  
    "feeGrowth0Hi": tickHi.feeGrowthOutside0X128.toString(), 
    "feeGrowth1Low": tickLow.feeGrowthOutside1X128.toString(),  
    "feeGrowth1Hi": tickHi.feeGrowthOutside1X128.toString(),
    "feeGrowthInside0LastX128": position.feeGrowthInside0LastX128.toString(),
    "feeGrowthInside1LastX128": position.feeGrowthInside1LastX128.toString(),
    "feeGrowthGlobal0X128": feeGrowthGlobal0.toString(), 
    "feeGrowthGlobal1X128": feeGrowthGlobal1.toString()}
    
    return PoolInfo
}


const ZERO = JSBI.BigInt(0);
const Q128 = JSBI.exponentiate(JSBI.BigInt(2), JSBI.BigInt(128));
const Q256 = JSBI.exponentiate(JSBI.BigInt(2), JSBI.BigInt(256));


function toBigNumber(numstr){
  let bi = numstr;
  if (typeof sqrtRatio !== 'bigint') {
    bi = JSBI.BigInt(numstr);
  }
  return bi;
};


function subIn256(x, y){
  const difference = JSBI.subtract(x, y)

  if (JSBI.lessThan(difference, ZERO)) {
    return JSBI.add(Q256, difference)
  } else {
    return difference
  }
}


async function getFees(feeGrowthGlobal0, feeGrowthGlobal1, feeGrowth0Low, feeGrowth0Hi, feeGrowthInside0, feeGrowth1Low, feeGrowth1Hi, feeGrowthInside1, liquidity, decimals0, decimals1, tickLower, tickUpper, tickCurrent){
    
    let feeGrowthGlobal_0 = toBigNumber(feeGrowthGlobal0);
    let feeGrowthGlobal_1 = toBigNumber(feeGrowthGlobal1);

    
    let tickLowerFeeGrowthOutside_0 = toBigNumber(feeGrowth0Low);
    let tickLowerFeeGrowthOutside_1 = toBigNumber(feeGrowth1Low);

    
    let tickUpperFeeGrowthOutside_0 = toBigNumber(feeGrowth0Hi);
    let tickUpperFeeGrowthOutside_1 = toBigNumber(feeGrowth1Hi);

    
    let tickLowerFeeGrowthBelow_0 = ZERO;
    let tickLowerFeeGrowthBelow_1 = ZERO;
    let tickUpperFeeGrowthAbove_0 = ZERO;
    let tickUpperFeeGrowthAbove_1 = ZERO;

    
    if (tickCurrent >= tickUpper){
        tickUpperFeeGrowthAbove_0 = subIn256(feeGrowthGlobal_0, tickUpperFeeGrowthOutside_0);
        tickUpperFeeGrowthAbove_1 = subIn256(feeGrowthGlobal_1, tickUpperFeeGrowthOutside_1);
    }else{
        tickUpperFeeGrowthAbove_0 = tickUpperFeeGrowthOutside_0
        tickUpperFeeGrowthAbove_1 = tickUpperFeeGrowthOutside_1
    }

    
    if (tickCurrent >= tickLower){
        tickLowerFeeGrowthBelow_0 = tickLowerFeeGrowthOutside_0
        tickLowerFeeGrowthBelow_1 = tickLowerFeeGrowthOutside_1
    }else{
        tickLowerFeeGrowthBelow_0 = subIn256(feeGrowthGlobal_0, tickLowerFeeGrowthOutside_0);
        tickLowerFeeGrowthBelow_1 = subIn256(feeGrowthGlobal_1, tickLowerFeeGrowthOutside_1);
    }

        
    let fr_t1_0 = subIn256(subIn256(feeGrowthGlobal_0, tickLowerFeeGrowthBelow_0), tickUpperFeeGrowthAbove_0);
    let fr_t1_1 = subIn256(subIn256(feeGrowthGlobal_1, tickLowerFeeGrowthBelow_1), tickUpperFeeGrowthAbove_1);

    
    let feeGrowthInsideLast_0 = toBigNumber(feeGrowthInside0);
    let feeGrowthInsideLast_1 = toBigNumber(feeGrowthInside1);

    
    let uncollectedFees_0 = (liquidity * subIn256(fr_t1_0, feeGrowthInsideLast_0)) / Q128;
    let uncollectedFees_1 = (liquidity * subIn256(fr_t1_1, feeGrowthInsideLast_1)) / Q128;
    console.log("Amount fees token 0 in lowest decimal: "+Math.floor(uncollectedFees_0));
    console.log("Amount fees token 1 in lowest decimal: "+Math.floor(uncollectedFees_1));
    
    
    let uncollectedFeesAdjusted_0 = (uncollectedFees_0 / toBigNumber(10**decimals0)).toFixed(decimals0);
    let uncollectedFeesAdjusted_1 = (uncollectedFees_1 / toBigNumber(10**decimals1)).toFixed(decimals1);
    console.log("Amount fees token 0 Human format: "+uncollectedFeesAdjusted_0);
    console.log("Amount fees token 1 Human format: "+uncollectedFeesAdjusted_1);
}


async function Start(positionID){
    var PoolInfo = await getData(positionID);

    
    var Fees = await getFees(PoolInfo.feeGrowthGlobal0X128, PoolInfo.feeGrowthGlobal1X128, PoolInfo.feeGrowth0Low, PoolInfo.feeGrowth0Hi, PoolInfo.feeGrowthInside0LastX128, PoolInfo.feeGrowth1Low, PoolInfo.feeGrowth1Hi, PoolInfo.feeGrowthInside1LastX128, PoolInfo.liquidity, PoolInfo.Decimal0, PoolInfo.Decimal1, PoolInfo.tickLow, PoolInfo.tickHigh, PoolInfo.tickCurrent);

}


Start(5);
```